# Gronwall's inequality with time-dependent terms

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inequality, dynamical-systems

Gronwall's inequality bounds the solution of a certain form of ODE or system of ODEs: citing from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4090462/gronwall-lemma-for-system-of-linear-differential-inequalities),

for a single differential inequality
$$ u'(t) \leq a_1\,u(t) + a_0 $$
the Gronwall lemma guarantees that
$$u(t)\leq\, u(0)\,e^{a_1 t} + \frac{a_0}{a_1}\, (e^{a_1t}-1) \,.$$

What would the inequality be if $a_0 = a_0(t)$?

Comment: There are more general formulations that amount to: If $v$ is a solution of the equality $v'=a_1v+a_0$, and $u(0)\le v(0)$, then $u(t)\le v(t)$ for all $t>0$.

Comment: A proof for an even more general statement can be found in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3366874/dynamical-systems-proof-that-ft-is-less-than-or-equal-to-gt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still apply the solution formula, or at least the steps for it. With the integrating factor you get
$$
(e^{-A_1(t)}u(t))'\le a_0(t),
$$
where $A_1'(t)=a_1(t)$, $A_1(0)=0$. This can be integrated to $t>0$ giving
$$
u(t)\le u(0)e^{A_1(t)}+\int_0^ta_0(s)e^{A_1(t)-A_1(s)}\,ds.
$$
Not so coincidentally the right side is the solution formula for the solution of the equality version of the inequality.

Comment: By "solution formula", do you mean your answer in the other question you linked?

Comment: I mean the solution formula for first-order linear DE. That is, for the equality version of the inequality. Which in this sense connects to the linked more general statement.

Comment: Thanks. I posted a community wiki showing that the RHS is the solution (I do have the signs of the $A_1(s)$ and $A_1(t)$ terms switched, though... did I make a mistake?) Is that what the proof looks like?

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot! Would you be willing to comment on how to show the bound/monotonicity of $\frac{d}{dt} \frac{y(t)}{u(t)}$?

Answer (score 1):

For my own reference.

**The proof of the inequality stated in the original question is:**
We find the solution of the ODE
$$ u'(t) = a_1 u(t) + a_0 . $$

Define the integrating factor
$I(t) = e^{\int_0^t -a_1 ds} = e^{-a_1t}$ so that $I'(t) = -I(t)a_1$.

Multiplying both sides of the equation by $I(t)$, we get

$$ u'(t) I(t) - a_1u(t)I(t) = a_0 I(t)$$
where the LHS is $\big(u(t)I(t)\big)' = u'(t)I(t) - u(t) I(t)a_1$.

Integrating both sides,
$\int_0^t \big(u(s)I(s)\big)' ds = \int_0^t a_0 I(s)ds$
gives
$$u(t)I(t) - u(0)I(0) = a_0 \int_0^t e^{-a_1s}ds.$$

Plugging in $I(t) = e^{-a_1 t}$ and $I(0)=1$,
$$ u(t)e^{-a_1 t} - u(0) = a_0 \int_0^t e^{-a_1s}ds.$$
Hence, the solution is

$$ u(t) = u(0)e^{a_1t}+ a_0 \int_0^t e^{a_1t-a_1s } ds .$$

Then, it can be shown that $y(t) \leq u(t)$ for any $y(t)$ satisfying the inequality version of the ODE
$$ y'(t) \leq a_1 y(t) + a_0$$
by using the product rule on
$$ \frac{d}{dt} \frac{y(t)}{u(t)},$$ and showing that this derivative is negative. Hence, if $u(0)=y(0)$, then $y(t) \leq u(t)$. (I don't know how to do this part, though; while the [proof in the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality#Proof_2) is straightforward, the additional term $a_0$ changes things. )

**Proving the time-dependent case:**

Using the same method with integrating factors, now with $$ I(t) = e^{\int_0^t -a_1(s)ds}.$$
Also suppose that $A_1'(t) = a_1(t)$, so that
$$ I(t) = e^{-A_1(t)}.$$

Then, the solution of the equation $u'(t) = a_1(t) u(t) + a_0(t)$ is

$$u(t) I(t) - u(0)= \int_0^t a_0(s) I(s) $$
is
$$u(t)e^{-A_1(t)} -u(0) = \int_0^t a_0(t) e^{-A_1(s)} $$
i.e.
$$ u(t) = u(0)e^{A_1(t)} + \int_0^t a_0(t) e^{A_1(t) - A_1(s)} ds.$$

Showing the inequality, that any solution is less than or equal to the above solution, is similar to the above.